# How can I check the balance of the account in ink smart contract

Tags: ink, balances

Let's say that I deploy `erc20` contract in ink and transfer to Bob 100 tokens, now I want in my contract to see did Bob having any amount of tokens, just to be sure that he can use  my contract? How to do that?

In substrate pallets there is `free_balance()`, and how to do it in ink smart contracts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some previous answers that might be useful for you :

- [How can I determine the native Balance of an Account/Address in Ink!](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/3001/how-can-i-determine-the-native-balance-of-an-account-address-in-ink)
- [How can I call my pallets and it functions in a smart contract?](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/6029/how-can-i-call-my-pallets-and-it-functions-in-a-smart-contract)
- [How to call runtime functions from a contract](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/1951/how-to-call-runtime-functions-from-a-contract)

You can check the [ink examples](https://github.com/paritytech/ink-examples/tree/main) repository as well.